# Ruby Command line application to update Facebook Status

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, command-line

i am intrested in developing a command line application using ruby to update Facebook status. To do this i need to be authenticated. Does Facebook Api provides authentication using comman line applications?
i checked facebook api there is no support for command line applications. so how should i proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to authorize user without their interaction with browser.

> Our OAuth 2.0 implementation does not include explicit support for application built for desktop operating systems. However, if your app can embed a web browser (most desktop frameworks such as .NET, AIR and Cocoa support embedding browsers), you can use the client-side flow with one modification: a specific redirect_uri.

See *Windows, OS X and Linux native apps* section of [Authentication documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

There is additional way of authentication that will work without browser, it's called [**Authentication for Devices**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/) which is currently supported only for **limited number of partners** and **not available for general use**.

Comment: thanks but i wonder how these desktop applications like Nimbus or yahoo messanger works?

Comment: There is way to implement authentication flow in desktop application, it's just not suitable for command-line application due to need of interaction in browser...