# facebook on curl command line

Tags: command-line, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

I am trying to make an application using cURL on commandline for my MIPS based linux box. 
As test steps Using FB Graph API, I am able to post status updates, photos etc on to the user's wall. But for this I had to get the access token from Graph API explorer using browser based login on PC first.

For my target system(for which application will be used), I do not have access to browser. How does my application in this case, get a valid access token? Is there not any way or endpoint or API through which my application can talk using curl and get an access token on behalf of user?

Is going via browser the only valid way to get login through and receive access token?

Here I am talking about getting USER ACCESS-TOKEN...
app access-token I am able to get.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible.
See this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/10223476/693133][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10223476/693133